# How to get Shiny to load data frame on VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, shiny

So right now I have this shiny popup for some project that I am working on:

[image]

I've been able to run this fine on RStudio but I am working on a website using React to I would like to be able to work on this using VSCode. I have the R extension installed, "languageserver", and these packages installed which are required:

```
install.packages('BiocManager')
BiocManager::install('dplyr')
BiocManager::install('shiny')
BiocManager::install('edgeR')
BiocManager::install('tidyr')
BiocManager::install('ggfortify')
BiocManager::install('pheatmap')
```

I just need to get shiny to popup on  my VScode and when I run my program I get this message:

```
Warning messages:
1: The select input "gene" contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.
2: The select input "factor" contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance. See the Details section of the ?selectizeInput help topic.
```

Again, I can run R files on VSCode perfectly fine, its just this Shiny which does not work.

Comment: You're getting a warning, not an error. The app will not launch at all anyway? There is no other message?

Comment: Perhaps solvable by this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377489/5221626

Comment: I am not getting anything else besides that message; in that stack overflow I don't know where I would even change the choices = namelist any where in my files

Comment: See the link it points to: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html

Comment: I just dont think the messages have anything to do with my my shiny wont create a popup, is it possible that shiny just doesn't work with VSCode?